# How to login at multiple users at once on converse.js

Tags: javascript, xmpp, converse.js

I'm developing a web chat using `converse.js`, and I need to login at multiple users at same time. For example, `alex1`, `alex2` and `alex3`, and keep them logged with session active.

What do you think it's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean having XMPP multiple accounts logged in within one webpage? Converse.js doesn't support that usecase.

> What do you think it's the best way to achieve this?

I'm not sure it's a good idea, but you could probably achieve this by creating a new XMPP connection for each XMPP account you want to connect with. This would however greatly increase the amount of traffic and if you are using BOSH (XMPP over HTTP) then it would greatly increase the amount of XMLHttpRequests being made.

As I've mentioned, converse.js doesn't support such a usecase, so you would have to write your own client or greatly customize/modify converse.js to accept and work with multiple XMPP connections.

Converse.js uses [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im) to make XMPP connections, so you would need to make multiple instances of Strophe.Connection.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think we're going to use multiple frames, and customize a lot of things in your library within our needs. Forward messages, send files, multiple chat tabs (to fill inside a frame), etc.